# how to fix : error 21 in sqlite 3 while using exec? cpp

Tags: c++, sqlite

im making a project and im working with sqlite 3 to make database.
im trying to check if a user exist to make a login request, but somehow it doesn't work(the table users already created).
when im using exec, it doesn't get into the callback function, and im getting result 21, which is apparently an error because of the call, but i cant understand how to fix it.

```cpp
//this is the callback function
int loginCallBack(void* var, int count, char** data, char** columns)
{
    int lol = 0;
    std::cout << count;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("%s = %s\n", columns[i], data[i] ? data[i] : "NULL");
        }
        *(bool *) var = true;
    }
    else
    {
         *(bool *) var = false;
    }
    return 0;
}

int LoginManager::login(std::string username, std::string password)
{
    std::string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = " + username+ " AND password = "+ password + ";";
    bool* ifLoginSucceded = new bool;
    int res = sqlite3_exec(m_database.db, sqlStatement.c_str(), loginCallBack, ifLoginSucceded, nullptr);
    std::cout << res;
    if (*(ifLoginSucceded))
    {
        m_loggedUsers.push_back(LoggedUser(username));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

when im running, the final sqlstatement string looks like this:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "username" AND password = "password";

I've also tried to run this with the sqlstatement:
SELECT * FROM users;
which also doesn't work,and im getting the result 21

thanks for help

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In your example there is no code that conects to the database. And anyway this is not a C++ question.

Comment: You can use the last parameter of `sqlite3_exec` to obtain a detailed error message.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sqlite3_exec()` for this at all. Use a [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) and bind the values you're given to parameters in the query.